# PDO Generate placeholders for binding from array and single value for a multiple INSERT statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to generate a single insert statement that will insert multiple rows. I have and array of values, which is what I am wanting to insert into a table that all use the same `userkey`.

I have tried using a named PDO parameter and binding to that, then passing in the role array during execute but that doesn't work. So I moved on to placeholders, but I can't get that to work either.

I call my function like `addUsersRoles(1, [100,101,102]);`

And looking at the generated SQL I get:

`INSERT user_roles (userkey, roleid) VALUES (?,?),(?,?),(?,?)`

Which I think is the correct format for inserting multiple records.

Based up on that, what I am trying to generate is:

`INSERT user_roles (userkey, roleid) VALUES (1,100),(1,101),(1,102)`

How can I combine the power of PDO's binding to a SQL statement in this manner?

```
public function addUsersRoles($userkey, $roles = []){

        $in = str_repeat('?,', count($roles) - 1) . '?';

        $base_user_sql = 'INSERT user_roles (userkey, roleid) VALUES ';

        $sql = $base_user_sql;

        foreach ($roles as $role) {
            //$sql .= "(:USERKEY, $in),"; // Didn't Work
            $sql .= "($in),";
        }
        //Remove trailing comma
        $sql = rtrim($sql, ',');

        $db   = static::getDB();

        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        //$stmt->bindValue(':USERKEY', $userkey, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        return $stmt->execute($roles);
    }
```

Comment: To leverage the benefits of prepared statements, prepare() should be called once only (outside the loop), then execute() may be called multiple times on the statement ($stmt). With this approach, you can insert one row at a time, but setting autocommit to false, this could give good performance. In this example, prepared statement is misused.

Comment: @marekful He's not calling either of them in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `count($roles)` when making `$in`. It's always just `?, ?`. You just need the count of roles when repeating that for all the rows. You can use `array_fill` to create an array of `(?, ?)` strings, and then `implode` to put commas between them.

You also need to insert create an array with alternating keys and roles, and use that as the parameters when executing.

```
public function addUsersRoles($userkey, $roles = []){

    $values = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($roles), '(?, ?)'));
    $base_user_sql = 'INSERT user_roles (userkey, roleid) VALUES ';
    $sql = $base_user_sql . $values;

    $keys_and_roles = [];
    foreach ($roles as $role) {
        $keys_and_roles[] = $userkey;
        $keys_and_roles[] = $role;
    }

    $db   = static::getDB();

    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    return $stmt->execute($keys_and_roles);
}
```

Comment: As you already have to `foreach` over the roles, the `array_fill()`, `implode()` seems like a waste to build an array just to create the values part - IMHO.

Comment: I consider it a simpler way to create a repeating string. If you concatenate the strings in the loop, you have to do that trim at the end to clean it up.

Comment: `array_fill()` & `implode()` vs `.=` & `rtrim()`, wonder which I will be sticking with.

Comment: I've seen lots of people post code that uses the rtrim method, so it's popular. I dislike special cases like that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use placeholders as well. Look at the following example:

```
public function addUsersRoles(string $userKey, array $roles = []): bool 
{
    $values = [];
    $inputParameters = [':user_key' => $userKey];

    foreach ($roles as $index => $role) {
        $rolePlaceholder = ':roleid' . $index;
        $values[] = sprintf('(:user_key, %s)', $rolePlaceholder);
        $inputParameters[$rolePlaceholder] = $role; 
    }

    $sql = 'INSERT INTO user_roles (user_key, roleid) VALUES ';
    $sql .= implode(', ', $values);

    $db = static::getDB();

    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    return $stmt->execute($inputParameters);
}
```

This code will generate a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO user_roles (user_key, roleid) VALUES (:user_key, :roleid0), (:user_key, :roleid1), (:user_key, :roleid2), (:user_key, :roleid3), (:user_key, :roleid4);
```

And the $inputParameters will be like this:

```
[
    ':user_key' => 'some user key',
    ':roleid0' => 1,
    ':roleid1' => 2,
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've simplified it a bit, but this splits into two parts that are done together.  The first is to generate the SQL...

```
INSERT user_roles (userkey, roleid) VALUES (?,?),(?,?),(?,?)
```

This code just loops through the roles and adds `(?,?),` for each one.

The second part is building up the bind data.  As the SQL needs a list of the data in the order userkey, roleid pairs, as it's building the SQL, it also adds these values to a data array at the same time.

So the main code comes out as...

```
public function addUsersRoles($userkey, $roles = []){
    $sql = 'INSERT user_roles (userkey, roleid) VALUES ';
    $binds = [];
    foreach ( $roles as $role ) {
        $sql .=  "(?,?),";
        $binds[] = $userkey;
        $binds[] = $role;
    }
    //Remove trailing comma
    $sql = rtrim($sql, ',');
    $db   = static::getDB();

    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    return $stmt->execute($binds)
}
```

(Although I haven't been able to test the execute part).

You should also make sure any errors are being dealt with as well.

Comment: Your answer was also very good, but I ultimately chose @Barmar answer.